# Unable to resolve ModuleNotFoundError when deploying a Django App on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, modulenotfounderror

I keep getting the following error in my logs when I try to deploy my app on Heroku:

```
    2021-03-16T19:03:43.053580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn todo.wsgi:application`
2021-03-16T19:03:46.709810+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-16T19:03:46.711200+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14087 (4)
2021-03-16T19:03:46.714536+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-16T19:03:46.720381+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726159+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726161+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726163+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in 
init_process
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726164+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in 
load_wsgi
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726165+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726166+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi 
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726167+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726167+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726167+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726168+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726169+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726169+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726170+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726178+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'todo.wsgi'
2021-03-16T19:03:46.726318+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-16T19:03:46.757758+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-16T19:03:46.757919+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-16 19:03:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-03-16T19:03:46.862677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-03-16T19:03:46.968721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-16T19:04:06.117589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=awesomedjangotodolistapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a901a457-1b6b-4520-85d4-7c8282840444 fwd="49.207.195.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2021-03-16T19:04:06.459303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=awesomedjangotodolistapp.herokuapp.com request_id=34922463-fb00-4fc3-a8ec-37c802dcfd1f fwd="49.207.195.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-16T19:04:10.265232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=awesomedjangotodolistapp.herokuapp.com request_id=44c8e399-efc6-4693-b571-07bf37c773da fwd="49.207.195.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https   
2021-03-16T19:04:10.606797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=awesomedjangotodolistapp.herokuapp.com request_id=54b508bf-12f7-4cdc-bc7e-86f797c60b91 fwd="49.207.195.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Apparently the error has to do with the line  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'todo.wsgi'` which I can't wrap my head around because my Procfile *does* exist in the todo directory.
Here's my directory tree:

[image: todo_list is the app directory]

todo_list is the app directory. My Procfile looks something like this:

```
web: gunicorn todo.wsgi:application
```

How do I solve this problem? todo.wsgi is not a module/directory but todo is, isn't it? The version of my Procfile works for other people but doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Procfile to the following:

```sh
web: gunicorn todo.wsgi
```

Comment: I did, it says the same thing (No module named todo.wsgi)